# OpenGL noob questions

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

This is using an OpenGL port called lwjgl. So lets say I have a double array:

```
double[] orthographic={1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,
0.0,0.0,-2.0,5.0,
0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,};
```

And I have a vertex shader:

```
String vertexshader = "#version 430 core"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertexin;"  
//Does this have to be a dvec4? 
        + "layout(location = 1)uniform mat4 orthographic;"  
//Does this have to be a dmat4?
        + "void main(){"
        + "gl_Position =   orthographic * vertexin;"
//Is this multiplication correct? Do I need to reverse it?
        + "}";
```

And lets also say I have a theoretic completely functioning fragment shader. So I want to send the orthographic array into the mat4. How would I do this given that it is a double array? Can I just use gluniformmatrix4()? Do I need to make mat4 into dmat4? If so that would mean I have to make vec4 into dvec4 because of casting. Well if I was to do this then OpenGL would throw an error

```
Failure in compiling vertex shader. Error log:
0(2) : error C7011: implicit cast from "f64vec4" to "vec4"
```

I have googled this but to no avail. There is literally only 4 things matching the search none of them relevant. Am I playing with the wrong things here? My screen resolution is

```
static public int height=720;
static public int width=height/9*16;
```

Should I be using normalized coordinates [-1,1] or just ordinary coordinates [-whatever,whatever] so that I can use floats instead of doubles. If I make a vec4 that is say 2 in any direction then it is off the screen. But could I make my coordinates range half of width for x and half of height for y but so that they would be still on the screen? Say y could be 360,-360 and y could be 640,-640 and still be on the screen?

Comment: Are you sure your graphics card supports double precision in the shaders, and that the vec4 type elements are in double type?

Comment: Ah... I don't have the GPU. Thank you. Will use floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You really should not use double-precision matrices in the first place.

Up until recently GPUs only supported single- or half-precision floating-point in the programmable pipeline. In fact, for many years there was some disagreement over how many bits single-precision floating-point even had. D3D9 only required 24-bit single-precision in the *pixel* shader stage and AMD/ATi hardware followed that requirement pretty much until they rolled out D3D10 class GPUs (now *desktop* vendors all agree that single-precision is 32-bit).

#### This will fix your problem and save memory too:

```
float[] orthographic = {1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f,
                        0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f,
                        0.0f,0.0f,-2.0f,5.0f,
                        0.0f,0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f };
```

---

#### Having said that, yes... at the very least, that uniform needs to be declared `dmat4`.

This extension ([`GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/gpu_shader_fp64.txt)) introduces the necessary function to set a double-precision 4x4 matrix uniform:

`glUniformMatrix4dv (...)`

*Incidentally, there is a different extension ([`GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_attrib_64bit.txt)) necessary to use double-precision vertex attributes.*

Now, since you are using Java, your actual function name and the parameters you pass will be a little bit different, but the point is you need a GPU that supports FP64 to even do this. And there is very little real-world benefit to this, Java teaches some bad habits sadly; not all of floating-point's problems can be solved by doubling the precision.

Comment: Those extensions are all ***core*** for GLSL 4.30, I brought them up so you could read more about them if you are interested. You can see that FP64 vertex attributes were actually introduced *after* double-precision shading. You should also know that while FP64 shading is an optional feature in DX11, GL4 requires it.

Comment: Thank you. The next question will disturb you to your core but I must be sure: You can have decimals in floats just by adding an f after it? True/False? Java applicable?

Comment: `f` is a precision ***suffix***. It means that the floating-point constant is single-precision. Without it, languages that are based on C (*e.g.* C++, Java, C#, GLSL) will *usually* (GLSL is the major exception to the rule ;P) assume that the constant is double-precision. Having the language assume double-precision is particularly annoying in the more type-safe C derivative languages.

Comment: By Jove! It's true! Now I can rule the little metaphorical world I live in! Hahah. No but that sentance actually makes no sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Finding the documentation for `glUniformMatrix4dv()` is kind of a challenge. It's not mentioned in the GL4 man pages: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml. While things missing in the man pages is not unusual, the spec has the wrong prototype (`const float *value` for the last argument, on page 124 of the latest 4.4 spec). The text implies that it really takes a `double *`, and the header files confirm it.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: You often will not find GL4.x functions/additions in `/man/html/...` on the GL site. You might have to look in `/man4/html/...`, though this is even absent from the GL4 man pages. As for the prototype, yeah they tried to re-use the part of the document for `void UniformMatrix{234}fv` by changing it to `void UniformMatrix{234}{fd}v` and neglecting to account for the change in passed parameter type. The actual extension spec. which I linked to has the proper prototypes

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Yeah, I was looking at the GL4 man pages. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/ is what you get to if you click "OpenGL 4 Reference Pages" on the home page, and the title and list of functions corresponds to GL4. It looks like `man` in the URL aliases to the latest, which currently is `man4`. To get older versions, it's `man3` and `man2`. I know that I shouldn't count on the man pages, but it's still always tempting to go there because it's so convenient.